# Get filename from database with Talend

Tags: excel, database, file, for-loop, talend

I have the file location in my database and i would loop on each file location to open the file and extract data in Talend to insert in my database .

I get the file location with a request and i get something like that :

[image]

So, i would loop on each row, and put the FILE_PATH result in a component Excel.

How can I do this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You have to use tFlowToIterate : it will create a loop based on incoming data (filepath here)
tDBInput>tFlowToIterate>tFileInputExcel
In tFileInputExcel, just put the global variable coming from your tFlowToIterate as the filepath.
Your case will be similar to this talend example with tFlowToIterate : https://help.talend.com/r/LffDtDyh9DacekHL_U0CGw/798DoNGV_8WjRj6C42_HJQ